# Generating dynamic constraint layout || Unable to create list of views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

im creating dynamic layout for forms im receiving from remote DB.

This is my approach:

```
        val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)
        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        var createdViews: ArrayList<View> = ArrayList()

        //parse fields to appropiate view
        formFields.forEach{
            var view: View? = null
            when(it.type) {
                "textField" -> {
                    view = EditText(this)
                    //view.hint = it.hint
                }
                "checkBox" -> {
                    view = CheckBox(this)
                    //view.isChecked = it.isChecked
                }
            }
            view!!.tag = it.id
            view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            views.add(view)
            constraintLayout.addView(view)

        }


        //set constraints for these views
        var previousItem: View? = null
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
        createdViews!!.forEach{
            if (previousItem == null) {
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP
                )
            } else {
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    previousItem!!.id,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
                )
            }
            previousItem = it
        }
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

Im having trouble with creating list of views becouse var createdViews: ArrayList = ArrayList() doesn't seem to work
Also maybe there is better way to create form programmatically like this. I will gladly enjoy any advice

Comment: Do you update `createdViews` anywhere?

Comment: Actually it kinda started to work after i came after short break. Not sure why it didn't work before :P Must've been some tiny issue i didn't even notice. That's why i got so annoyed and thought i can't set a list of view so i reached out for help. Eh